# Evenly distribute tick space vertically sbpts subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to adjust the vertical space between the ticks in the figure. So that they are distributed evenly throughout the height of the figure. Because there are values that overlap.
I have tried to get the height and amount

```
    sbpts.set_yticks(close_values)
    sbpts.set_yticklabels(new_ticks_labels)

    sbpts.tick_params(axis='y', pad=0)
    sbpts.set_ylabel('Precios del cierre')

    fig_height = fig.get_figheight()  # Obtiene la altura de la figura
    num_ticks = len(new_ticks_labels)  # Obtiene la cantidad de marcas en el eje y

    # Calcula el espacio de forma uniforme
    space = fig_height / num_ticks

    # Ajusta el espacio vertical entre los subplots
    fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=space)
    fig.tight_layout(pad=space)
```

[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: This lacks a complete [mre], but I’d guess the vale’s used for the y-axis are strings, not numbers

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand what you mean.
I think the problem has to do with the property I'm using.
But in the documentation I can't find anything related to the space or the margins between the ticks @TrentonMcKinney

Comment: This question is not reproducible without **data**. This question needs a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). Always provide a [mre] **with code, data, errors, current output, and expected output, as [formatted text](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)**. If relevant, plot images are okay. If you don't include a mre, it is likely the question will be downvoted, closed, and deleted.